# C: Struct of arrays as array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I was wondering wondering if it was possible to read a struct of arrays as an arry of structs.

e.g.

```
typedf struct foo{
    int a[];
    int b[];
    int c[];
}foo_t;

main:
foo_t foo ={.a={11,12,13},.b={21,22,33},.c={31,32,33}};
```

So foo[0] would contain {11,21,31}, foo[1] would contain {12,22,32} and foo[2] would contain {13,23,33}

any idea?

Comment: Use C++ and overload the subscripting operator for the structure.:)

Comment: An array inside a struct must have a constant bound, except for the last struct member.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an array of the struct.

```
typedef struct foo{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}foo_t;

main:
foo_t foo[] ={{11,21,31}, {12,22,32}, {13,23,33}};
```

So foo[0] would contain {11,21,31}, foo[1] would contain {12,22,32} and foo[2] would contain {13,23,33}

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. An array of structs is structurally and semantically different from a struct of arrays.

Comment: you might add this to comment instead of answering here as this is not the full explanation